# Unable to fetch a key data while iterating through an object

Tags: javascript, angular, object

I am iterating through an object. However, it is not catching all the keys. It is catching only a few. It is especially not catching organic_results key. I don't understand why. Kindly help.

```
 for (var key in this.writeItOutput){ 
    
      if(key == "inline_people_also_search_for"){
      console.log("inline_people_also_search_for")
    }

} 
 
  if(key == 'organic_results'){

    console.log("inside organic_results");
}

  if(key =="related_questions"){
console.log("inside related questions");
 
}


  if(key =="related_searches"){
 console.log("Inside related_searches");
}
      
}
```

All the keys are:

[image]

Comment: I removed references to json from the question since it’s not used in the question

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

you have a bracket that closes your for-in loop just before this line:

```
if(key == 'organic_results'){
```

so the steps your script executes are the following:

1. start for-in loop
2. set `key` variable to a key from `this.writeItOutput` iteration
3. check whether the `key` equals to "inline_people_also_search_for"
4. go to step 2 until all keys in `this.writeItOutput` are iterated
5. finish the loop
6. run if blocks

So when you reach the step 5, your `key` variable equals ONLY ONE key in `this.writeItOutput`. What you may want to do is to put all these if blocks inside your for-in loop:

```
for (var key in this.writeItOutput){ 
   if(key == "inline_people_also_search_for"){
     console.log("inline_people_also_search_for")
   }

// } - this bracket is the problem
 
  if(key == 'organic_results'){
    console.log("inside organic_results");
  }

  if(key =="related_questions"){
    console.log("inside related questions");
  }


  if(key =="related_searches"){
    console.log("Inside related_searches");
  }
      
}
```